# Proposal to change the wording of Off-Topic reason redirecting to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, close-dialog

As it currently stands, it is:

> Questions must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow.

That kinds of just redirects the users to SO, which is good. But it is like saying goodbye. Wouldn't it be better to make it like this:

> Questions must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After your code is working you can edit this question for reviewing your working code.

It is like saying, "go there to fix this, and then come back and we'll help you."  It can have a good impression on new users and may help with getting some users back from SO after getting their code corrected.

How about that?

**Update**

I tweaked it a bit:

> Questions must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After your code is working you can edit this question for getting a code review.

**Update 2**

Just thought to add the link of Stack Overflow to the message after I found myself adding it in [a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/how-do-i-work-with-inheritance-and-abstract-classes-in-java#comment46335_29342) because the user was new and didn't have an account on Stack Overflow. I thought he might be left wondering why he would overflow the stack if he hadn't known that a site with that name existed.

> Questions must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). After your code is working you can edit this question for getting a code review.

Answer (score 2):

Just what I was wanting for a while now. :-) If they already became aware of CR, they may keep it in mind for the future.  We need that kind of exposure as we try to get out of beta.  I just hope that *every* new user sees this first, otherwise our occasional game of "hot potato" with SO will continue.

Comment: If you can post other such messages which are automated then perhaps they can also be discussed. I could find only this so posted it.

Comment: @AseemBansal: You mean commenting with a "This belongs on SO... come back afterwards if you need a review" for relevant questions?  I used to do that during my flagging days, but I suppose I can keep doing it with close votes if needed.  Speaking of which, _this_ request should be put into the "on-hold" messages as well.

Comment: Another question relevant to migration that I started to meta stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189977/encouraging-users-to-flag-off-topic-posts-before-making-a-comment-that-it-is-off It has been marked duplicate so maybe we can push the original question to get something done. Opinions?

Comment: Actually I was asking about any messages placed including the on-hold messages.

Comment: @AseemBansal: Okay.  Yeah, that will help since those messages are for the OP.  The voters among us should just do the voting and not have to worry about posting our own message.

Comment: We can use them in comments also. No problems there. That is also helpful till the on-hold message is displayed.

Comment: @AseemBansal: True, as that will depend on how long it takes for five people to put in a close vote.  I guess I'm just "exhausted" from it after finally earning Deputy. :-P I have no intentions to reach Marshal, though.